# Finding MongoDB Document by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongohq, database

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB with my database hosted on MongoHQ (Now compose.io). I have a general understanding document IDs are converted to hex strings but I can't figure out how to retrieve a document using its ID.

My document has the ID `_id: ObjectId("53f13064b5a39cc69f00011b")` as in that's how it's displayed in Compose's interface. When I retrieve the document by brute force, the ID is shown as `_id: 53f13064b5a39cc69f00011b`.

What do I use in Node.js to retrieve this document? The query:

```
systemData.find({_id: "53f13064b5a39cc69f00011b"}).toArray(function(err, data) {//do stuff}
```

returns an empty set but so does querying with an object ID object

```
systemData.find({_id: new ObjectID("53f13064b5a39cc69f00011b")}).toArray(function(err, data) {//do stuff}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: By brute force I just mean getting all documents in the collection and finding the one I'm interested in and looking at it in the console.

Comment: You're querying with a _new_ `ObjectID`, hence the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
systemData.find({_id: ObjectID("53f13064b5a39cc69f00011b")})
```

No need for the "new" on the beginning.

Comment: Fantastic thanks! Basically the only permutation I hadn't tried.